# For Loop for sub view in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, for-loop

As we are having issues while looping the below views dynamically, so requesting you to please look into the same and let us know any good and reliable solution for the same which could really a great help to me.

**Layout.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Meda name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="tick"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="tick"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText4"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorHint="#000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Code.java**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            RelativeLayoutll2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll2);
            EditText testname = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            testname.setText("Med");
            testname.setTextColor(000);
            EditText testname1 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            testname.setText("Hello");
            testname.setTextColor(000);
            EditText testname3 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            testname.setText("Hello");
            testname.setTextColor(000);
            EditText testname2 = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            testname.setText("Hello");
            testname.setTextColor(000);
            ll2.addView(testname);
            ll2.addView(testname1);
            ll2.addView(testname3);
            ll2.addView(testname2);
        }
```

Please refer this image. I want to be like this when I select the number in the `Spinner` where it must display that number of fields.

[image]

Comment: why not your using  ListView

Comment: i had done it dynamically sir i want to try differently thats y thank u

Comment: good . well done 
just post your answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll3);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parentLayout, false);
            parentLayout.addView(view);
        }
```